# How do I connect Netgear DM111PSP v2 to ATT U Verse?

Tags: dsl-modem

I purchased a new modem to replace the ATT provided NVG510. For some reason the Netgear setup wizard is not allowing me to setup my DSL connection.

I have entered my PPPoE login and password, however, I am still not connected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure uVerse is not PPPoE.  Also only the AT&T provided hardware contains the necessary certificates to authenticate the service, so essentially you're out of luck.  :(